# Access to Windows 7 log from a remote machine

Tags: windows-7, event-log

I'm trying to access with EventViewer (from a Windows XP Prof) to a remote machine with Windows 7 (Seven).

Before I started the Service "RemoteRegistry" I received an "Access Denied". After started the service I can connet to the machine Log  (in EventViewer app) but when i clik on any log as "Application" or "Security" I receive a "privilege" error.

Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

By default when trying to carry out tasks that require elevated privileges (such as this one) you need to connect to the remote Windows 7 system using the credentials of the explicit local Administrator account on that system, or the credentials of a member of the Domain Administrators group if its part of a domain. UAC prevents other users, even members of the local Administrators group, doing this. What account are you using on the XP Pro machine to authenticate the connection?

[This article on MSDN about UAC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709628(WS.10).aspx) explains this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using, onto Window Seven machine, an account that belongs to the local Administrator group. I am in a Workgroup and not in a domain.

The account I use onto the Windows XP Pro belongs to the Administrator group too and the credentials onto the Windows XP Pro and onto Windows Seven are the same.

Probably Do I have to give some more privilege to the Seven user?

Comment: No using a member of the Administrators group is not sufficient, you have to use _The_ Administrator's account. You can disable\change this particular UAC behavior, or disable UAC completely to work around this. The reason is to do with automatic elevation which is active for The Administrator but not for members of the Administrators Group.